# Routing: Visible parameter value on hovering over ui-sref disappears when clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am using `angular-ui-router` module of AngularJS and have the following `ui-sref` which when I hover over shows `http://localhost:3000/u/bob#/123/pin/4567`, but when I click on it, I get only `http://localhost:3000/u/bob#/123/pin/` on the browser's URL address bar and get the parameter value `4567` lost.

**HTML code (index.html):**

```
<a ui-sref="users.maker">
    <!-- stuff -->
</a>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
.state('users', {
    url: '/:foo',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: '/partials/index.html',
            controller: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams',
                function($rootScope, $stateParams) {
                    //stuff
                }]
        }
    }
})

.state('users.maker', {
                        url: '/pin/:bar',
                        templateUrl: '/partials/users.maker.html',
                        controller: ['$stateParams', '$scope', '$http',
                            function($stateParams, $scope, ) {
                                //stuff
                            }]
                    })
```

Could somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried defining your ui-sref as following?

`ui-sref="users.maker({ param })`

Comment: The page  I have `<a ui-sref="users.maker">
    <!-- stuff -->
</a>` does not have the value of `bar` parameter. The HTML code is shown is in the `index.html` page.

Comment: @skip I am saying that it should. Unless I am misunderstanding you, you are trying to go to `users.maker` with a parameter but you are not passing one.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic `ui-sref` do not work in `ui-router`. A function using `$state.href()` could be used to resolve this issue.

So `<a ui-sref="users.maker({ foo: bar })">...</a>` could be done by following:

**HTML**

```
<a  href="{{goToState('users.maker', bar)}}">..<a>
```

**Inside AngularJS Controller**

```
$scope.goToState = function(state, param) {
    return $state.href(state, {foo: param});
}
```

This is with `angular-ui-router` version `0.2.10`.

For more:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395